# simple IF ELSE statement not matching arithmetic answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm making a maths test, where if the user puts the correct input i want it to print correct.I have this

```
answer = (input) ("What is your answer?")
maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))


if answer == maths:
    print ('Correct')

else:
    print('Wrong')
```

However its not working. It doesn't print correct, it just prints wrong whether input is correct or not.
cheers aron

Comment: Could you be more specific how is it not working? [ask]

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You might check the `maths` value, `operation`, ... That is the way you could fix the bug.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 2 and not Python 3? What does `print(repr(answer))` and `print(repr(maths))` output?

Comment: Also, in Python 2 you'd use `raw_input()`, and explicitly convert the output to an integer.

Comment: yea sorry im using three

Comment: `answer` type is string and `maths` type is int, if you compare then first parse answer value into int type and then compare like:
`maths == int(answer)` which will give you `Correct`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a *string* value, not an integer. You cannot compare integers and strings and expect them to be equal:

```
>>> '42' == 42
False
```

Convert your input to an integer first:

```
answer = input("What is your answer?")
answer = int(answer)
```

This can lead to a `ValueError` exception if the input was not numeric however. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for options on how to handle that possibility.